# Getting html from template tag

Tags: javascript, html, html5-template

Im trying to get the html of the below to add to a widget. The widget is not working and when I output the variable below. The html is not exactly the same. You can see the HIT tags have been moved to the top?

```
<template id="hit-template">

            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            brand
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            price
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @{{#hits}}
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                          @{{fname}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @{{email}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @{{age}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @{{/hits}}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </template>

<script>
 var hitTemplate = document.querySelector('#hit-template').innerHTML;
</script>
```

OUTPUT of `hitTemplate`:

```
 {{#hits}}

                    {{/hits}}
                <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            brand
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            price
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody><tr>
                        <td>
                          {{fname}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{email}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{age}}
                        </td>
                    </tr></tbody>
            </table>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Joe

Comment: we need to see some more code, not just the result

Comment: What are you using? `@{{#hits}}` is not vanilla HTML or JS.

Comment: Hi @sam this is the code. I've extracted this out and doing the same.

Comment: @DBS I'm using Laravel and Hogan.

Comment: Your code is not being preprocessed by your template preprocessor, or it's not being recognized. That's why you find `{{#hits}}` out of the table, because web browsers don't allow that _HTML_ inside  `tbody` tags, and prints them out

Comment: @I.G.Pascual Ah OK that makes sense. At this stage it hasn't got to Hogan. I basically just need the contents of the template tag, as a string. Is this possible?

Comment: does Hogan actually use `@` char for templating?

Comment: @I.G.Pascual I'm using blade so I'm just making sure blade ignores it

Comment: I'm using `knockout-js` for templating, and what we actually do is to `<script type='text/html' id='footemplate'>` the templates to make web browsers ignore them, never used the `<template>` tag... Give it a try ;)

Comment: I've just changed the template tag to your suggestion and its outputting exactly as it should! I wish I understood!

Answer (score 0):

You should do this instead:

```
<script>
 var hitTemplate = document.querySelector('#hit-template').content.innerHTML;
</script>
```

The code is in the `content` property.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of that *"..while the parser **does process the contents of the  element** while loading the page, it does so only **to ensure that those contents are valid** ..."*, so the problem is the the content is processed and is not valid.

Try to use `script` element with type set to `text/template` like this:

```html
<script>
function showTemplate() {
  alert(document.querySelector('#hit-template').innerHTML);
}
</script>
<script id="hit-template" type="text/template">
 <table class="table">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>
    name
    </th>
    <th>
    brand
    </th>
    <th>
    price
    </th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   @{{#hits}}
    <tr>
     <td>
     @{{fname}}
     </td>
     <td>
     @{{email}}
     </td>
     <td>
     @{{age}}
     </td>
    </tr>
   @{{/hits}}
  </tbody>
 </table>
</script>
<button onclick="showTemplate()">show template</button>
```